# startindex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was going through the Sign and Distribute wizard to publish my app but I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXLgU.png) error with no other information. If anyone has any experience with this error can you explain what I should do so I can continue?

[image]

Comment: So does your app work correctly when you run it? Just the publishing fails?

Comment: Yes. I figured out what was happening...

Comment: @msloan11 what happened, i encountered this issue several times already but i can't seem to figure out what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The package name had one-too-many periods in it.

Comment: I renamed the package but after publishing successfully, it generated more than 1 APK. have you encountered this issue?